# Windows Phone emulator not starting (couldn`t setup the UDP port)

Tags: windows-phone-8, hyper-v, windows-10, windows-phone-emulator

After updating Windows 10 to build 10061 windows phone emulators (all 8.1 and 10) stopped starting. I get the following error: 
"Windows Phone Emulator is unable to connect to the Windows Phone operating system. Couldn`t setup the UDP port"

I tried "reparing" emulators, but nothing changed.

[image: error]

Hyper-V manager shows that virtual machine works, and it can be started directly from Hyper-V manager.
As i said, in previous windows 10 TP builds it was OK.

[image: emulator works in background]

Comment: No, but I don't think it might change something.  I'll check it later

Comment: If nothing else that might allow VS to configure the port... Whether it will work when not running as admin, who knows?  Might be worth a Connect to not only report but also to possibly get the correct port number.

Comment: I don't know if it helps but I had this issue in build 10049 but it disappeared after an update. I am currently on 10069.

Comment: @varun where you find 10069 build? As i know, 10061 is the last one...

Comment: @Will nothing changed, the same error

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do you see your "Virtual Switch" information under: Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections? If not, you can try to recreate your "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch" again from Hyper-V to see if that resolves your issue. Try these steps below:

1.) Open Hyper-V

2.) Shutdown any existing configured Phone emulators.

3.) Click on "Virtual Switch Manager"

4.) Click on the "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch"

5.) Remember what the settings are displayed there (because you will delete it and recreate it)

6.) Delete the existing "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch" by clicking "Remove"

7.) Click "Apply" and "OK"

8.) Re-create the "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch" by clicking the "New virtual network switch" and use the same settings you remembered in Step 5.

9.) Then try to F5 from Visual Studio - which should configure a new emulator on the right virtual switch.

Comment: No need for steps 5 and 8. Once you try to run the enumlator from VS the virtual switch will be re-created.

Answer (score 57):

The solutions above did not work for me. I found out that the issue was with the Hyper v adapters so I decided to deleted them which caused hyper -v to create them again.

**These are the steps**

1. Run cmd as admin and enter the following commands

   set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1

   start devmgmt.msc
2. This will startup the device manager and show the list of hyper v network adapters
3. Right click and uninstall all hyper v network adapters
4. Open Hyper v manager and delete the virtual machines
5. From Virtual Switch Manager (right side of hyper-v manager), delete all internal switches
6. Restart the system and run visual studio and launch emulator

See this for more info http://www.gfi.com/blog/how-to-remove-hidden-network-adapters-from-virtual-machines/

Comment: Thanks ! Since two days the emulator wouldn't work and I don't know why. Now it's fixed !

Comment: seriously - if I could upvote this 1000 times - I tried everything else before this (couldnt launch visual studio android emulator) Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Of all the solutions in Stackoverflow, yours is the only one that works for me.. every time. Thank you!

Comment: Great! thank you for this procedure! it helped me to fix the ridiculous issue!

Comment: Thanks! This is the only solution that worked for me. BTW I had to restart my PC after step 4, because Hyper-V was unabled to remove the switch, but it could after restart. Weird...

Comment: Thanks for sharing. For me this was also the only solution that worked. So, after a couple of hours i finally can continue!!

Comment: 5th step is a bit counfuse - on the right side there are many options, it sould be explained better

Answer (score 8):

I had similar problem, i tried the various solutions offered (cleaning up the Hyper-V images and network switches), reinstalling Hyper-V, reinstalling Visual Studio, restoring to Old System Restore point - but none of my actions didn't resolved the problem.

But i tried below action which fixed the problem, off course some might able to resolve the problem with above steps and other answers provided.

In my case, my virtual adapter doesn't have network connectivity. I shared my wi-fi adapter connectivity to virtual adapter. This fixed for me, i can able to deploy apps into emulator without any crashes.

[image: wi-fi adapter sharing option]

Comment: you know what...? I LOVE YOU!

Comment: Good call @mahender! this helps for me too!

Answer (score 5):

For me, the following steps worked:

1. Open Hyper-V manager and delete all emulators
2. From Virtual Switch Manager (right side of hyper-v manager), delete all internal switches
3. From Control Panel->Network and Sharing Center, disable the virtual ethernet port for windows phone emulator
4. Start Visual Studio and start emulator from there (Just deploy a project)

   Update: Your old connection will stay disabled and a new connection will be created. If you want to delete the old connection, go to device manager, find the connection and choose "uninstall"

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was a problem with my notebook modem. It is a Sierra Wireless EM7345 4G LTE. As soon as I deactived it the Win10 Mobile Emulator worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

For me all above solutions didn't work. 
Maybe because my Ethernet is disabled.

My solution is similar to other:

1) delete vm's from hyper-v

2) delete all internal switches

3) create manually new switch and select wifi

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSlgY.png)

4) install vm profile

5) start it :)...

after 6h endly

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you are unable to delete internal switches in Hyper-V UI:

1. go to regedit
   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\vmsmp\Parameters\SwitchList
2. delete Windows Phone entry (or all)
3. reboot computer
4. start VS and run emulator which will set everything up

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and tried many solutions and got the emulator working by doing the below steps:

1. Remove all the virtual switches from "Virtual Switch manager"
2. Restart your system.
3. Goto Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network and Sharing Center -> Advanced sharing settings 
   [Advance sharing screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DTL4.png)
4. And enable "Turn on Network discovery" and "Turn on file and printer sharing" for all network profiles.
5. Start emulator.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

The steps suggested by Magani Felix above worked for me, but I had to apply two additional steps:

1. After deleting virtual switches from devmgmt.msc, the remaining virtual switch entry can't be removed from hyper-v manager anymore (step 5). However, just leaving it there was ok.
2. The first time I started the emulator from Visual Studio it could not connect. When I looked at the virtual switch in hyper-v manager, it had been created as a private virtual network. Shutting down the emulator from both Visual Studio and hyper-v manager, and then changing the internal switch to internal virtual network solved the issue. Afterwards, the emulator would start from Visual Studio and connect.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 pro.

After attempting all the above, and similar suggestions from other threads, what ultimately worked for me was to:

- Uninstall Hyper-V: Add/Remove -> Turn Windows Features On / Off
- Uninstall Visual Studio Emulator for Android
- Reboot
- In Device Manager, "Uninstall" all remaining "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter" instances found under "Network Adapters" node
- Reboot
- Reinstall Hyper-V
- Reboot
- Reinstall Visual Studio Emulator for Android
- Download a device profile and launch
- profit

Not all the reboots may have been necessary, but I had been banging my head against this for too long.

I believe this was caused due to me adding and removing Hyper-V a few times in the past, and some VirtualBox conflicts (which I currently do not have installed, it hasn't played nice with Hyper-V for me in the past).

Thanks for all tips above, hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The solution offered by Silmar worked for me. All-in-all it appears that at least for Windows 10 Pro that one should install Hyper-V but not configure any virtual switches as the emulator installer will configure things properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this OPTION

1.) Open Hyper-V

2.) Shutdown any existing configured Windows Phone emulators.

3.) Delete the existing Phone emulators you see in the list

3.) Click on “Virtual Switch Manager”

4.) Click on the “Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch”

5.) Delete the existing “Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch” by clicking “Remove”

6.) Click “Apply” and “OK”

This should work.
**If this does not, then do this:**

Now, open “Network Connections”

You will see there “vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)”

But hey, you deleted this same switch in OPTION 1, but still it shows in the Network Connections page.

Now open Device Manager, Expand “Network Adapters”

You will see the names appearing under Network Adapter match the same as “Device Name” mentioned in “Network Connections” window

Find out the correct “Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter” to be removed.

Now, in Device Manager, right click the correct Network Adapter and choose “Uninstall”.
This should disappear from the list.

Open “Network Connections” and see that “vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)” will no longer be present there.

Open Visual Studio, run the project in your desired emulator.

This time everything will work fine and the Emulator will boot up Windows 10 or Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread but just thought I would chime in.

What fixed it for me was going into "Turn windows features on or off"... unselecting all the hyper v boxes... restarting my computer... then selecting all the hyper v boxes again in "turn windows features on or off" and restarting again....

This fixed it for me. I tried the solutions mentioned above but they did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled for some days with this issue. 
After I have read all forums and references, I have found the solution and fixed it. The solution was as following.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681694(v=vs.105).aspx

**Interference from other virtualization or networking software and drivers**

Other virtualization and networking software and drivers can interfere with the virtual network used by the emulator to communicate with Visual Studio. The types of software that may cause a problem include:

```
-Virtualization software other than Hyper-V.

-VPN clients.

-Software firewalls.

-Antivirus applications that hook into the network stack.

-Network monitoring or logging tools.

-Other system monitoring software.
```

After I uninstalled some software to interfere, I can run the emulator successfully. 
Hope this help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Hyper-V Manager.
2. Open Virtual Switch Manager on the right side like pictured below:

   [image: Open Virtual Switch Manager]
3. Remove all Virtual Switches that contain "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch" and "Microsoft Emulator NAT Switch" like pictured below:

   [image: Remove Virtual Switch]

   4. On Visual Studio, Click on your emulator that you want to deploy your app on.