# Windows Phone Emulator in Windows 10 not working

Tags: emulation, win-universal-app, uwp

When I run a UWP app in Windows 10 RTM, it gives error like "Unable to Verify that virtual machine is running"? After I restart my Visual Stuido, the emulator will stay on the OS start for a long time, then failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First please try to make sure that you have met all the System requirements for the emulator for Windows Phone as described in the following article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Mt162269.aspx.

Since Windows Phone Emulator runs as a virtual machine on Hyper-V, please refer to this link: Troubleshooting Hyper-V (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc742454.aspx) to check if this issue is caused by the Hyper-V.

After that please try with below steps which has been posted by @Prashant H Phadke - MSFT in here([Windows Phone emulator not starting (couldn`t setup the UDP port)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903619/windows-phone-emulator-not-starting-couldnt-setup-the-udp-port)):

1.) Open Hyper-V

2.) Shutdown any existing configured Phone emulators.

3.) Click on "Virtual Switch Manager"

4.) Click on the "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch"

5.) Remember what the settings are displayed there (because you will delete it and recreate it)

6.) Delete the existing "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch" by clicking "Remove"

7.) Click "Apply" and "OK"

8.) Re-create the "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch" by clicking the "New virtual network switch" and use the same settings you remembered in Step 5.

9.) Then try to F5 from Visual Studio - which should configure a new emulator on the right virtual switch.

Besides, please also try to troubleshoot the emulators based on here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681694(v=vs.105).aspx , although it is for Windows Phone 8 emulator, but some workarounds should work for the Windows Phone 10 emulator.

If the above information still can not help, please try to repair or reinstall your Visual Stuido.