# Visual Studio Emulator for Android is not working: mscorlib.dll.so not found

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-emulator

After I configured Hyper-V and managed to get it [running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903619/windows-phone-emulator-not-starting-couldnt-setup-the-udp-port), the [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx) is starting up. I can see my splash screen, but then the app is exited. This is the output log:

```
InspectorDebugSession(1): StateChange: Start -> EntryPointBreakpointRegistered
InspectorDebugSession(1): Constructed
Android application is debugging.
03-25 10:24:48.717 D/dalvikvm( 1251): Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-25 10:24:48.749 D/dalvikvm( 1251): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/MyApp.Droid-1/libmonodroid.so 0xa8f89c78
03-25 10:24:48.749 D/dalvikvm( 1251): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/MyApp.Droid-1/libmonodroid.so 0xa8f89c78
03-25 10:24:48.761 W/monodroid( 1251): Using override path: /data/data/MyApp.Droid/files/.__override__
03-25 10:24:48.761 W/monodroid( 1251): Using override path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MyApp.Droid/files/.__override__
03-25 10:24:48.761 W/monodroid( 1251): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/MyApp.Droid/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
03-25 10:24:48.761 W/monodroid( 1251): Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MyApp.Droid/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
03-25 10:24:48.761 W/monodroid( 1251): Trying to load sgen from: /data/app-lib/MyApp.Droid-1/libmonosgen-2.0.so
03-25 10:24:48.761 W/monodroid( 1251): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/MyApp.Droid/files/.__override__/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so
03-25 10:24:48.761 W/monodroid-debug( 1251): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8915,server=y,embedding=1
03-25 10:24:48.917 W/monodroid-debug( 1251): Accepted stdout connection: 43
03-25 10:24:49.693 D/Mono    ( 1251): Image addref mscorlib[0xb948bb30] -> mscorlib.dll[0xb948b0f0]: 1
03-25 10:24:49.697 D/Mono    ( 1251): AOT module 'mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/MyApp.Droid-1/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
03-25 10:24:49.697 D/Mono    ( 1251): AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/2970/46c3f7e0/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/MyApp.Droid-1/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
03-25 10:24:49.705 D/Mono    ( 1251): Unloading image data-0x95e99010 [0xb948bb90].
Could not connect to the debugger.
InspectorDebugSession(1): HandleTargetEvent: TargetExited
InspectorDebugSession(1): Disposed
```

I tried to uninstall the data (app, mono, xamarin) in the emulator, restarted Visual Studio/emulator, but nothing of it helped. Why is it such a pain when using an Android simulator? Don't know how Android apps are developed if none of the simulators can't be used in "production".

I should mention that it works on the device and in other simulators like Xamarin Android Player, simulator from Android SDK, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a try:
[Xamarin Forms Android App Crashes Running Debug with VS Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800168/xamarin-forms-android-app-crashes-running-debug-with-vs-android-emulator/35779589#35779589)

In short:

**1. "Could not connect to the debugger" issue:**

1. Start the Hyper-V manager
2. Select the emulator you are trying to use
3. Right-click, hit settings
4. Click processor
5. Click Compatibility
6. Set checkbox “Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor version”

**2. The missing libaot-mscorlib.dll.so issue:**

Go to the properties of the Android project, hit tab “Android options”, and unselect “Use Fast Deployment”.