# Universal Windows 10 Emulator not starting up OS

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, mobile-emulator

The Windows phone emulator running Windows 10 has been working since I've installed it and last time I used the emulator was a few days ago. Now for some reason when I load my application emulator does not load the OS.

here's the steps I go throuogh to run the app :

-Run "Mobile Emulator 10.0.10586.0 720p 5 inch 1GB (which is my usual emulator to run)"

- Message box saying "Configuring  Windows Phone for debugging ... "
- Another message box appears saying "Click "Retry" to run the emulator in elevated mode. :

> You do not have permission to modify internal Hyper-V network adapter settings, which are required to run the emulator

- Click retry on the message box
- "Are you sure you want to run Windows Phone Packages?" Click Yes
- Configuring Windows Phone for debugging box still running
- Phone emulator runs but stuck on "OS is starting..."
- Message box appears after leaving it running for roughly 15 mins :

> "The emulator is unable to connect t the device operation system :
>   Couldn't set up the UDP port. Some Functionality might be disabled.
>   will add this to the steps"

I've followed the instructions from forums to go to Hyper-V Manager and delete the virtual switches and virtual machines - which doesn't work. And I also have Hyper-V enabled on windows features.
Any other solutions would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

UPDATE : so I've left it running just to see if it works eventually, now another message box appears saying :

> The emulator is unable to connect to the device operation system : Couldn't set up the UDP port. Some functionality might be disabled.

UPDATE : So I managed to fix it .. a little. It works for the other apps I have as well as newly created universal windows projects. But this specific app doesn't . I notice that this specific one has the "Configuring Windows Phone for debugging" message pop up whereas the other ones don't.

Comment: It seems like Network problem. Check this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29926443/2945356

Comment: Followed one of the solutions, the emulator loads up to the home screen / dash board - but it stops there, does not load the application . a message says "Unable to start remote debugging on the device. The device returned error code : 800770019".
Ill look into that

Answer (score 0):

Why not start fresh? 
New OS, new install, everything from scratch.

And don't forget to not play with UAC, OS permissions, the firewall, and do not install anything which would install virtual network adapters. Like OpenVPN, USB modems (including an iPhone), etc.

This is a solution, because your problem could be anything.

Comment: I'd have that solution as a last resort, because backing up everything I have on this computer and reinstalling all the SDK / extensions on visual studio would take hours. I find it weird that It just suddenly stops working out of nowhere.
Thanks for your input, I will keep this solution in mind

Comment: Disable the windows firewall,  go to Hyper-V and try to power on any machine, see if there are other network adapters present on the system.

Comment: So I ran the machine on Hyper-V, and it is running fine, but running the emulator on visual studios doesn't. It is still stuck on the "OS is starting..." screen.