# Windows Mobile Emulator : Error Code 80070019

Tags: c#, emulation, hyper-v, windows-10-universal

This is a continuation of my previous problem with the emulator, found here :

> [Universal Windows 10 Emulator not starting up OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292634/universal-windows-10-emulator-not-starting-up-os?noredirect=1#comment60211266_36292634)

After trying out multiple solutions found online, none of them seem to work for me.

When I ran my app a couple of days ago it was working perfectly fine. But now when running the emulator I get a message "Configuring Windows Phone for debugging" and shortly after I get the following message :

> Unable to start the remote debugging on the device. The device returned error code : 80070019

and the emulator is just showing a blank screen.

When opening a new universal windows app project and running that emulator, it seems to work fine without any errors. So I am not really sure if the issue is the emulator or not.

On the Hyper-V Manager its status is showing that it is running, but with a blank screen on it also.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you running the same emulator on the new UWP app? On your computer, you could try going into `Add/Remove Programs > Visual Studio > Change > Repair`.

Comment: When running on the new UWP app, it seems to create a new VM on Hyper-V Manager automatically. Yes, I've done a repair and tried again but the same problem occured

Comment: Have you tried disabling Hyper-V and then re-enabling it? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_install. Follow the manual install.

Comment: I have tried disabling Hyper-V and re-enabled it but have not done the manual install. I will try it now and come back to you in a moment

Comment: I have done the manual install and disable and enable Hyper-V but still have the same problems

Comment: Did you try to restart the service after deleting the emulator? I always have to restart it to make it work again.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update my current status on this situation. I ended up having this unsolved, but luckily, I had a backup of the exact app and it somehow works without any problems, Thanks for your advice, may be useful for other people with the same problem