# Emulate deploy error in Apache Cordova hybride app

Tags: apache, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-emulator

when I debug my apache cordova project on VS2015 it shows a error message like this. How can solve this error. Please give any solution

**Error Message :**

> The emulator is unable to connect to the device operating system:
>   Couldn't set up the UDP port. Some functionality might be disabled.

Comment: did you have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903619/windows-phone-emulator-not-starting-couldnt-setup-the-udp-port) question ? It is always advised to test it on real devices rather than emulators.

Comment: Thanks  Arpit Vasani